# MVC C# Entity Framework error: the data reader is incompatible with the specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm getting an error after calling the following stored procedure:

```
var result = db.APP_Client_Update(clientID,[and other parameters here]).ToList();
```

And the error:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 
'ClientModel.APP_Client_Update_Result'. 
A member of the type, 'retcode', does not have a corresponding 
column in the data reader with the same name.
```

The stored procedure returns the following:
If I cant find the record then...

```
If @WorkflowID is null or not exists 
(Select 1 from Clients_Changes where ClientID = @ClientID)
BEGIN
    Select '-999' as retcode, 
'Unable to update client record, something is wrong' as retmessage
    Return 0
END
```

If successful...

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN
COMMIT TRANSACTION
Select '1' as retcode, 'Client Updated Successfully' as retmessage 
END
```

I've searched everywhere for a solution but cant seem to find one, I've made sure all my return types in my mvc solution match exactly to retcode and retmessage.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the point of such query in SP? The return code itself exactly says if client was updated or not and generating a message is IMHO responsibility of the application - not stored procedure. How did you map the procedure?

Comment: I mapped the stored procedure by adding the stored proc to my entity data model, then did a function import and created a complex type.  Which recognized retcode and retmessage as the return values of my stored proc.  I then added the EF 5.x DbContext Generator.  The above is a snippet of what my stored proc does, retcode and retmessage are just to let me know if I was successful or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was in the stored procedure after running SQL Profiler I was able to narrow down the error.